# how to replace characters or remove them in golfscript efficiently

Tags: golfscript

If I have a character list already, how can I remove certain character, or replace all occurrences of such character with another character?

Answer (score 2):

```
# remove any 'l'
'hello world' 'l'-
puts

# replace all 'l' with 'X'
'hello world' 'l'/ 'X'* 
puts
```

Please also have a look into the page for [GolfScript built-ins](http://golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html).